# Nash equilibria problem

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, nash-equilibrium, algorithmic-game-theory

I have a problem to solve the next exercise.

Two players call a number from 1 to 100. The winnings are distributed as follows: players always receive no more than 100 rubles in total, the most greedy gets what he asks for. More formally: if the players have chosen numbers a and b, then the payoff will be $(a,b)$   if  $a+b≤100$. If $a+b>100$, then the payoffs are $(a,100-a)$, if $b>a$,the payoffs $(100-b,b)$ , if $a>b$ and (50,50) if $a=b$.

Find all Nash equilibria  in this game.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(a, b)$ denote the selections of player $A$ and $B$.

I found the pure (deterministic) strategy combinations $(50, 50)$, $(51, 50)$, $(50, 51)$, $(51, 51)$ and all mixed strategy combinations where both players pick either $50$ or $51$ with some probability given to each to be the only Nash equilibria. All of these strategies will reward both players with $50$ payoff.

Any strategy with $a < 50$ or $b < 50$ is not a part of a Nash equilibrium due to the fact that the player selecting $< 50$ can always select $50$ or $51$ to get higher payoff. If $a = 50$, $A$ will always get $50$ (and the same obviously holds for $B$). Either due to $a + b \leq 100$ or due to the fact that if $a + b > 100$, then $50$ will be the lowest selection.

Any strategy with $a > 51$ or $b > 51$ is not a part of a Nash equilibrium due to the fact that the one player can improve by selecting one less than the other. For example, if $b \geq 52$, $A$ can improve by selecting $a = b - 1$.

If any player selects $50$ or $51$, the other can't get more than $50$ payoff. If $a = 50$, player $B$ can select any number $\geq 50$ to get $50$.

Thus, the only pure strategy combinations that are Nash equilibria are $(50, 50)$, $(51, 50)$, $(50, 51)$, and $(51, 51)$.

This might be made more clear by showing some cases:

- $(a, b) \rightarrow$ (Payoff for $A$, Payoff for $B$)
- $(50, 50) \rightarrow (50, 50)$ No player can improve.
- $(51, 50) \rightarrow (50, 50)$ No player can improve.
- $(50, 51) \rightarrow (50, 50)$ No player can improve.
- $(51, 51) \rightarrow (50, 50)$ No player can improve.
- $(49, 50) \rightarrow (49, 50)$ $A$ can improve by selecting $a = 50$ or $a = 51$. $B$ can improve by selecting $b \geq 51$.
- $(52, 50) \rightarrow (50, 50)$ $B$ can improve by selecting $b = 51$.
- $(52, 51) \rightarrow (49, 50)$ $A$ can improve by selecting $a = 50$ or $a = 51$.
- $(52, 52) \rightarrow (50, 50)$ Both players can improve by selecting $51$.

Comment: cfml: thank you very much for your help, so there are 4 cases for Nash equilibria . Could you please recommend me some sources (boos, web resources) for this kind of problems and solutions.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help! There are 4 cases of pure strategy Nash equilibria (a pure strategy is deterministic - no randomness involved). If also considering mixed strategies, which are strategies where players select moves according to some probability distribution, there are an infinite number of ways to assign probability between $50$ and $51$ (such as 50% to select $50$ and 50% to select $51$).

Comment: I haven't studied Game Theory in a few years, but when I did I really enjoyed this concise book: Essentials of Game Theory: A Concise, Multidisciplinary Introduction, by Kevin Leyton-Brown. Here is a video series that is very popular, that also has a complementary text book: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSVmOC_5zrE&list=PLKI1h_nAkaQoDzI4xDIXzx6U2ergFmedo.

Comment: Thank you again